# How often will a condition be calculated in a for loop?

Tags: for-loop, gml

I iterate over a huge `ds_list` and want to know if the condition (in this case the size of the `ds_list`) will be **calculated** after every loop again and again (which would be bad for the performance). In that case I would store the result in a temporary variable.

```
for (var i = 0; i < ds_list_size(huge_list); i++) {
    // doing something
}
```

Comment: I use GameMaker Studio 2.3.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `for` loop will run the "condition" expression on each iteration, meaning that it can be beneficial to store the list size in a temporary variable if it will not change during the loop. You may verify this by using a script with a `show_debug_message` call in it as a condition.